# Where do the whitespaces come from in this RDD?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

The aim is to transform the integers that reside in a file:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

into three arrays so it is possible to perform mathematical operations.

**Expected**

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

**Actual**

```
[[u'1', u' ', u'2', u' ', u'3'], [u'4', u' ', u'5', u' ', u'6'], [u'7', u' ', u'8', u' ', u'9']]
```

**Code**

```
txt = sc.textFile("integers.txt")
print txt.collect()
#[u'1 2 3', u'4 5 6', u'7 8 9']

pairs = txt.map(lambda x: x.split(' '))
print pairs.collect()
#[[u'1', u'2', u'3'], [u'4', u'5', u'6'], [u'7', u'8', u'9']]

pairs = txt.map(lambda x: [s for s in x])
print pairs.collect()
#[[u'1', u' ', u'2', u' ', u'3'], [u'4', u' ', u'5', u' ', u'6'], [u'7', u' ', u'8', u' ', u'9']]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be that the numbers are in unicode format instead of int.
You can solve it by casting them to int (see https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int)

```
>>> pairs = txt.map(lambda x: x.split(' '))
>>> print pairs.collect()
[[u'1', u'2', u'3'], [u'4', u'5', u'6'], [u'7', u'8', u'9']]

>>> pairs2 = pairs.map(lambda x: [int(s) for s in x])
>>> print pairs2.collect()
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
>>>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
pairs = txt.map(lambda x: x.split(' '))
// this return every concatenated character that separated by space ' ', which kind of similar to following function (lamda also aware of newline from file)
def AFunc(aString):
   returnArray = []
   tempString = ""
   foreach(char in aString)
      if char == ' ':
         if tempString != "":
            returnArray.append(tempString)
            tempString = ""
      else:
         tempString += char
   return returnArray


// ..
pairs = txt.map(lambda x: [s for s in x])
// this return every character in a string, which kind of similar to following function (lamda also aware of newline from file)
def BFunc(aString):
   returnArray = []
   foreach(char in aString):
     returnArray.append(char)
   return returnArray
```

http://www.python-course.eu/lambda.php